# Reusing Tcp Connection with Camel Netty

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty

I am using camel to build a tcp server. I am waiting for connections and responding to clients messages using the following route

```
<camel:route id="ServerListeningRoute">
    <camel:from ref="tcpServerEndPoint" />
    <camel:setBody>
        <camel:simple>Server Received from you: ${body}</camel:simple>
    </camel:setBody>
</camel:route>
```

It is working. I can connect to the server with telnet, sent a message and get back the response from the server.

Now i want to create a new route to send messages from my server to those connected clients but reusing the socket connection already established. I am not responding to a message previously sent by a client. These would be new Exchanges started from my server.

I have tried this

```
<camel:route id="ServerSendingRoute">
    <camel:from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=60s?amp;delay=25s" />
        <camel:setBody>
            <camel:simple>This is a message from the server</camel:simple>
        </camel:setBody>
    <camel:to ref="tcpServerEndPoint" />
</camel:route>
```

But it is not working. The server is receiving its own produced messages since the to endpoint is opening a client connection to the server.

Is it possible with Netty and Camel to reuse the established connection? Do i need to extent the netty component somehow? Any workaround you can think of?